# Nginx/Php : Proxy included php script

Tags: php, nginx, proxy

Let's say my website is located in `/srv/http/www` and is available at `www.mydomain.com`.

I'm trying to have a subdomain `devel.mydomain.com` to be a place where I can test features before releasing them. The features' code is in `/srv/http/www-devel`

The idea is that, when trying to access `devel.mydomain.com` all ressources available in `/srv/http/www-devel` are considered, and all non available ressources are retrieved in `/srv/http/www` as a fallback. Consequently, just moving all files in in `/srv/http/www-devel` to `/srv/http/www` (and potentially overwritting existing files) will deploy my features.

The following nginx config works great for almost every ressources :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name devel.mydomain.com;
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/20-devel.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/20-devel.error.log;
    ssl_certificate         ...;
    ssl_certificate_key     ...;

    index                   index.php index.html;
    root                    /srv/http/www-devel;

    location ~ /\.          { deny all;                           }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off;  }
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off;  }

    location /              { try_files $uri @fallback;           }
    location @fallback      { root /srv/http/www;                 }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass          unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index         index.php;
        include               fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Still the issue is in the processing of php files. If I put in `/srv/http/www-devel` a php script that requires some ressources, and if those ressources are not available in `/srv/http/www-devel`, the php interpretor will not go look in `/srv/http/www`. How can I enable this behaviour at php level ?

Edit: Also I noticed that the `location ~ \.php$` directive doesn't go fetch php pages in the devel directory. How can I enable the fallback in the directive as well ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to use fallback directories in PHP is the [include path](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).

If you load files with like that:

```
require_once 'src/Foo/Bar.php';
```

and you have configured your include path so:

```
set_include_path('/srv/http/www-devel:/srv/http/www');
```

then PHP will first try `/srv/http/www-devel/src/Foo/Bar.php` and then `/srv/http/www/src/Foo/Bar.php`